# Jquery - addClass and removeClass not working inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery. The `addClass` and `removeClass` functions are not working properly in my code.
I tried debugging if function was not being called.
The logs are displaying 'test' and 'test1'but add class and remove class doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <spring-form:radiobutton name="residentCanadienImpot" class="radio-inline" path="indResidentCanadienImpot" id="residentCanadianImpotOui" value="O"/>
  <spring-tags:message code="lef.oui"/>
</label>
```

```js
var elementFiscaliteCanadaOui = $('#residentCanadianImpotOui');
var elementFiscaliteUsaOui = $('#residentAmericainImpotOui');
var elementFiscaliteAutreOui = $('#residentAutrePaysImpotOui');

if (valGroupeRadioindResIdentCanadaImpot === 'N' &&
  valGroupeRadioIndResidentUsaImpot === 'N' &&
  valGroupeRadioIndResidentAutreImpot === 'N') {

  console.log("test");

  $(elementFiscaliteCanadaOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
  $(elementFiscaliteUsaOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
  $(elementFiscaliteAutreOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');

  console.log("test1");
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML output of the spring code? Have you checked that the elements you're targeting exist in the DOM when the code runs? Have you put the jQuery code in a document.ready handler?

Comment: what you get inside if statement  if you do : - console.log(elementFiscaliteCanadaOui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
  $(elementFiscaliteCanadaOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
  $(elementFiscaliteUsaOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
  $(elementFiscaliteAutreOui).removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem')
```

To

```
      elementFiscaliteCanadaOui.removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
      elementFiscaliteUsaOui.removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
      elementFiscaliteAutreOui.removeClass("radio-inline").addClass('alertElem');
```

```js
let span=$(".text");
$("#change").click( function(){
  console.log(span);
  span.removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
})
```

```css
.text{
  margin-top:15px;
  padding:5px;
}
.blue{
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">
Change color from blue to red
</button>
<span class="text blue" >
  Hey
</span>
```

Comment: Although it is redundant to init a jQuery object again, it will not make any difference